# PHP: ternary operator inside include statement, variable undefined

Tags: php, variables, include, ternary-operator

I am checking a variable with ternary operator inside an include statement, but the variable becomes undefined:

```
<?php include('../partials/' . isset($altnav) ? $altnav . '.php' : '_nav.php'); ?>
```

Maybe `$altnav`  needs to be echoed? But I don't think that can be done inside the include statement.

Would I have to create a new variable and use two lines like this?:

```
<?php $pathpart = isset($altnav) ? $altnav . '.php' : '_nav.php';
include('../partials/' . $pathpart ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of operations. Enclose the ternary operation in parenthesis:

```
include('../partials/'.(isset($altnav) ? $altnav.'.php' : '_nav.php'));
```

Without the parenthesis, it concatenates '../partials/' to the result of isset($altnav) before checking the ? ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was not doing what you expected it to due to operator precedence as shown in the other answer, but assuming you're using the ternary operator for brevity, here are a couple of other points.

1. You can omit the outer parentheses. `include` is not a function, so they aren't required.
2. You don't need to use the ternary operator for this. [This is the purpose of the null coalescing operator that was added in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

   ```
   include '../partials/' . ($altnav ?? '_nav')  . '.php';
   ```